# REST api - search url

Tags: rest, web-api

I'm building a REST api and want to make sure to follow the best practices.
I need to expose a method which will return a 'Document' entity by its 'Lot' number.

It is possible that for a specific 'Lot', there's no 'Document' entity found. Also, property 'LotId' is not the key for 'Document' entity, it has his own key called 'DocumentId. What url structure shoul I use:

```
http://myUrl/Lots/{lotId}/Documents
```

or

```
http://myUrl/Documents?lotId=123
```

As it is posible to have no 'Document' attqached to a 'Lot', I don't want to return a `404 NotFound` if there's no document found, I would return a `200 Ok` with null

Comment: sounds good to me

Comment: with the first one you have the problem of the lot not existing at all vs lot with no document

Comment: @Ewan I would make a validation to return a 404 NotFounf if the lotId provided is wrong. So both url's make sense to you ?

Comment: they are fine. im not keen on 404s myself, or plural resource names. quotes around the lotid are prob not hood

Comment: Your question talks about a single Document as though the mapping from lot:document is 1:0 or 1:1 but your url says documents plural implying there are potentially many documents per lot. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to expose a method which will return a 'Document' entity by its 'Lot' number.

The methods are GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc. The HTTP verbs. Stick to them and think of what you are doing as state transfer, rather than issuing a command to the server. When you GET a resource you transfer the servers current state of that resource to the client. When you PUT you do the reverse.

The URI of a resource is a unique identifier. It doesn't really matter if it is

```
http://myUrl/Lots/{lotId}/Documents
```

or

```
http://myUrl/Documents?lotId=123
```

but it is important that a URI only points to one resource (that is what makes the URI unique). I prefer the first version to the latter

> As it is posible to have no 'Document' attqached to a 'Lot', I don't
>   want to return a 404 NotFound if there's no document found, I would
>   return a 200 Ok with null

You should return a 404. 200 means the state transfer was successful (from server to client via the GET command). But if no resource exists then this isn't the case. In REST there is no "not found" resource, you just return 404